# Boost::asio async_connect fails to solve when using "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1"

Tags: c++11, boost-asio

I am programming a tcp async client, but it fails to connect when I use "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1". I mean, 127.0.0.1 works great but localhost fails miserabily. Please, any help fixing it or at least any explanation of what is going on? Maybe I am missusing the tcp::resolver and its results/iterators?

PD: Funny thing is that when using sync version to connect it works with both adresses (I mean using boost::asio::connect(socket, endpoints, error);)

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

class client
{
public:
    client()
        : io_context(),
          acceptor(io_context),
          socket(io_context)
    {
    }

    void start(const char* host, const char* port)
    {
        tcp::resolver resolver(io_context);
        tcp::resolver::results_type endpoints = resolver.resolve(host, port);//

        socket.async_connect(endpoints->endpoint(), [=](boost::system::error_code error)
        {
            if (!error)
                std::cout << "Connecting to " << host << ":" << port << "\n";
            else
                start(host, port);
        });
    }

    void poll()
    {
        io_context.poll();
    }

private:
    boost::asio::io_context io_context;
    tcp::acceptor acceptor;
    tcp::socket socket;
};


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    if (argc != 1 && argc != 3)
    {
        std::cout << "async.exe <host> <port>" << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }

    const char* host = (argc == 1 ? "localhost" : argv[1]);
    const char* port = (argc == 1 ? "5031" : argv[2]);

    try
    {
        std::cout << "Trying to connect to " << host << ":" << port << "...\n";

        client c;
        c.start(host, port);

        while (true)
        {
            c.poll();
            Sleep(100);
        }
    }
    catch (std::exception& e)
    {
        std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have exactly this problem. The difference I found between when I used localhost and when I used an IP address (e.g. 127.0.0.1 or the IP address of the local machine) was that endpoints.size() was different. With an IP address endpoints.size() was 1 but with localhost endpoints.size() was 2. If I then drill down with a debugger I can see that one of these endpoints has an IP address of 127.0.0.1 and the other has an IP address of 0.0.0.0. What happens for me is that sometimes the endpoint list works OK, and sometimes it fails and I expect it is because only one of these endpoints actually provides a reliable route. It is easy enough to work around but strange behaviour otherwise. If I was guessing, I suspect that localhost provides both IP4 and IP6 endpoint whereas an IP4 address can only generate an IP4 endpoint. It still shouldn't fail though.